# Есть ли способ уменьшить контейнер, чтобы все его дочки уменьшились пропорционально не используя transform: scale?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
.child {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #5fba7d;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.paren {
  height: 5000px;
}
body {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<div class="paren">
  vrtvrtv
  <br>trvrvr
  <br>vrvrv
  <br>vrtvr
  <br>v
  <br>rfrv
  <br>r
  <br>v
  <br>r
  <br>v
  <br>r
  <br>v
  <br>v
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="child">
    Это плавающий блок
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот пример кода где у body стоит `transform: scale` из за этого элементы с `position: fixed;` перестают фиксироваться в определенной части окна. 
поэтому ищу рабочую альтернативу, без использования js еще можно уменьшить элемент

Comment: Вам подошёл мой ответ? Если да, то отметьте его, как принятый. Если нет, то уточните, что вам нужно в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Задавайте все измерения вместо `px` либо в `rem` (рекомендую именно этот способ из-за его простоты и сопровождаемости, тогда измерения будут относительно `font-size` тэга `html`), либо в `em` (тогда измерения будут происходить относительно `font-size` текущего элемента).